# Biztalk orchestration slows down on QA machine not on DEV

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-orchestrations

I have an BizTalk application which loops on a XML and send data to SQL server database. The orchestration works fine on the DEV machine throughout the process and is consistent.  But if I process the same file on the QA machine it starts with the same speed and then the performance keeps on degrading. There is no issue on the Database object, the throttling settings are the same compared to DEV. I restarted the machine. Not sure why QA is reacting this way for this application.

What are the areas to be checked?

Comment: Why can't you debatch the xml and use the SQL Adapter?

Comment: Is the data identical between DEV and QA?  I've seen this happen where a dev database had NULL values in a column that was populated on QA.

Comment: Are you using the old SQL adapter or the WCF-SQL adapter.   What version of BizTalk are you using.

Answer (score 1):

There are various factors which can cause this and overall your solution performance:

1. Is QA a shared environment, i.e. there are other solutions on it
   which may cause the slow down?
2. If you are sharing hosts on which orchestration is running then that host might be throttling due to various reasons such as memory issues etc, Use performance counter to monitor the host throttling state.
3. You may have too many persistent points in orchestration, since you        are looping and sending message to sql db in loop. if you are using send shape it will cause persistent point per send in loop,will degrade performance considerable.
4. Isolate the issue i.e. whether it is orchestration running slow or
   sending to SQL is taking time.
5. Tracking is turned on and DTA jobs are not running
6. Message clean jobs not running as expected in QA

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog about how to use SQL Server Profiler to capture the RPC call from BizTalk to SQL Server.  You could isolate whether SQL is causing the issue that way; capture the RPC call on DEV or QA, and then try running just the stored procedure on QA.  If it doesn't run as quickly as on DEV, that's your problem.  If it does, look at your BizTalk artifacts.

Here's the blog: http://blog.tallan.com/2015/01/09/capturing-and-debugging-a-sql-stored-procedure-call-from-biztalk/

Comment: the tracking database had reached the limit. I ran a process to remove old records

Answer (score 0):

BizTalk host throttled because DatabaseSize exceeded the configured throttling limit. Also The SQL Server Agent was not running on the server, so purge processes did not run. This looks to have built up the database size over time until Biztalk throttled the application due to the resources being low